# How to create multiple connection to one specific address in C++ GRPC client

Tags: c++, client, grpc, channel

I wrote a c++ grpc client, and wanted to create multiple connection by create  multiple channel, just like the hello world [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc#L110).

But only one connection for the specific address was created. So how to create multiple connection to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't see significant reasons for that (at least for basic use cases). You don't need to create multiple connections to have some kind of connection pooling (as you might want to do while connecting to RDBMS like PostgreSQL). The bandwidth of physical transport (TCP connection) will be fully utilized by the single network connection.

Comment: I see few:
1) to overcome tcp window size (if it cannot be configured)
2) to keep transferring on other tcp channels in case of single packet drop, thus fully utilize bandwidth
3) if endpoint is load-balancer (and I know this), then opening multiple connection will  increase a chance of higher request rate.